# Enumerating Windows?

Tags: c++, c, dll

I am making an application that needs some information from my Skype Window, I have found the main window, and the child window. I use WM_GETTEXT and show the buffer in a messagebox. It doesn't seem to work after I switch contacts a few times. Could anybody take a guess as to why this breaks after a few seconds?

```
case 2000:
  //Make options window here
  int len;
  char* buffer;
  HWND hWnd; //Main Window
  HWND chat; //Tconversation form, Caption is the contact's name.
  hWnd = FindWindow(L"tSkMainForm", NULL); //tSkMainForm is SKYPE
  chat = FindWindowEx(hWnd, NULL, L"TConversationForm", NULL); //GetWindow(hWnd,GW_CHILD);
  if (IsWindowVisible(chat)) {
    len = SendMessage(chat, WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, 0, 0);
    buffer = new char[len];
    SendMessageW(chat, WM_GETTEXT, (WPARAM) len + 1, (LPARAM) buffer);
    MessageBox(HWND_DESKTOP, (LPCWSTR) buffer, L"Testing", MB_OK);
  } else MessageBox(HWND_DESKTOP, L"We cannot find the window.", L"About Testing", MB_OK);
break;
```

So Just to give you a timeline of events, here is what happens.

I inject my DLL into Skype, it makes a menu, all that works. When I press my newly created button (ID 2000) I want to get the contact's name. Spy++ tells me caption of "TConversationForm" is the contact's name. This works for the first few contacts, but then Skype crashes.

I know I can use the Skype API, but I am using this more as a learning purpose than making a working tool.

Comment: Have you tried attaching to Skype in the debugger so you can catch where the application is crashing? If your code is directly causing the crash it should break into the debugger and take you right to the line in the file where it occurs.

Comment: I see `buffer = new char[len];`  Where is the matching `delete[]`?  I suggest you use OS functions (e.g. `HeapAlloc`) instead for injected code, since you don't control the C++ runtime Skype uses.

Comment: Use the accessibility interfaces. That's what they are for

Comment: @Ben Skype doesn't use a C++ runtime. It's a Delphi app. Look at the classname.

Comment: @cole the id of a button according to the q

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: That just makes use of `new[]` inside a hook even more fragile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to be lying about the length of your buffer. You allocate len characters, but then say that the buffer is size len+1. You'll need to allocate len+1 characters.

Skype on Windows is a Delphi application, built with VCL controls. The VCL uses a design that sometimes leads to window re-creation during the lifetime of a form. In other words the window handle can change and you could be left with a stale handle. That's another plausible failure mode.

Yet another possible failure mode is the fact that you are messing with the GUI from a non-GUI thread in a way that the application does not know about. It's more than likely that adding a menu behind the VCL's back is enough to cause failure.

You should not use HWND_DESKTOP as a window owner, and you appear to leak that text buffer.

I think your odds of succeeding on this path are low. Very low. I suggest that you use a supported automation interface.

Comment: Okay, I've fixed the len issue (I honestly did not see that, I've noted it as something I need to work on spotting in the future).

I am going to make the DLL create its own Window, too. So that VCL will not cause any further problems.

Comment: Since I cannot edit my comment after five minutes, I will add on to it here:

How would I go about ensuring my handle does not go bad? Would I simply find the window over again each time I need it? As far as I can tell Skype only has one instance of the class I am looking for at any one moment (The TConversationForm class). Thank you for all the help, too.

Comment: Yes, finding the window again and again would do. Of course, re-creation may not be hurting you.  but perhaps it is.

Comment: So, for my hWnd, since I defined it inside my if condition, does it create a new one each time that is ran? Skype does not crash if I just make the menu display a static messagebox (no memory allocation). So I assume it was/is a memory error.

Comment: You shouldn't get a crash if you have a stale window handle. Just the Win32 API calls will fail.